# Nrwl Nx and monorepo - handle package.json for particular apps

Tags: frontend, monorepo, nrwl-nx

for a frontend architecture I'm evaluating the usage of monorepo with Nrwl Nx. 
I understood from the docs that Nx strongly recommends the single-policy for dependencies (a root package.json with all the dependencies used by the apps and libs).

Today's goal is to find out if there is some solution to use for any reason a different dependency version for a specific application (aka more than one package.json inside the monorepo).

The scenario that I'm trying to analyze is the follow:

root package.json contains
somelib@1.2.2

This means that every app will use the version 1.2.2.
Everything works fine until the day cursedApp needs to use somelib@1.1.9.

There's any solution for this? I read the docs and this pattern is discouraged and the only proposal that I've found is to remove the cursedApp from the monorepo.

Thanks!
D

Answer (score 3):

https://nx.dev/packages/node/executors/webpack#generatepackagejson
it says:-

Generates a package.json file with the project's node_module dependencies populated for installing in a container. **If a package.json exists in the project's directory, it will be reused with dependencies populated.**

Comment: link seems to be broken now

Comment: I've done further tests on this topic and also had some workshops with Nx experts. At those days, there aren't any Nx official ways to accomplish the behavior. One of the suggested (and tested by us) workaround is to use npm aliases